# Obtaining an IP address from a web domain

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I would like to retrieve an IP address for any given domain, e.g. google.com would return the IP address `172.217.18.174`.

Using the following line on Google Sheets I always get the error

> "Imported XML content can not be parsed."

```
=importxml("http://xml.utrace.de/?query=google.com","//ip")
```

And I also tried the following ones without luck:

```
=importxml("http://xml.utrace.de/?query=google.com","//results/result/ip")
```

```
=importxml("http://xml.utrace.de/?query=google.com","/*")
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(IMPORTDATA("http://xml.utrace.de/?query="&A20), 
 "where Col1 contains 'ip'"), "<ip>|</ip>", "")
```

[image: 0]

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://tools.keycdn.com/geo?host="&A20, "table", 1), 1, 2)
```

[image: 0]